# Is there a phrase meaning specifically "as far as I know", as opposed to "as far as I see" ("quantum ab hoc")?

Tags: idiom

I know that "*as far as I see*" is "*quantum ab hoc [videtur]*". But is there a way to say specifically "*as far as I know*" or "*as far as I can tell*"?

I am trying to translate the lyrics of the Eric Bogle's song "Refugee" into Latin. It starts with:

> Joseph is 8 years old.
> **As far as he can tell**,
> he is a fine young boy
> with a big shining smile.

So, how would you translate "*As far as he can tell*" to Latin?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I think "as far as I see" and "as far as I can tell" are the same. It's the "as far as I know" that I was hoping to get an example of.

Comment: @cmw So, how would you say "*as far as he can tell*"? Would it be "*quantum ab eius loco*", or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **As far as he can tell,**
> he is a fine young boy
> with a big shining smile.

This is the same idiom as what you mentioned in the title, and so I would still recommend using *quantum videtur* (without the *ab hoc*, as it appears in Pliny and the *Scriptores Historiae Augustae*). Both are essentially "as it seems [to me, to him, etc.]." Magie, for example, translates it as "so far as it appears." The various ways of wording this in English are just variations on the same idea.

By itself *quantum videtur* should refer to the author, but if you want to make it clear that it is to the subject of the passage then just add *sibi*:

> **Quantum sibi videtur,**
> Pulcher est iuvenis
> Larga lumine ridens ( – – | – ˘ ˘ | – – )

Answer (score 3):

Another way to go is **Equidem**:

[L&S (II.B)](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=equidem&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) gives several examples among which this from Pliny:

> Aristoteles tradit et simul plures [cometae] cerni, nemini conpertum alteri, quod equidem sciam. [Aristoteles recounts that many comets (can) be seen at once. though, as far as I know, it wasn't verified by anyone else.]

If we have *quod*/*quantum* already, I think we could omit the *equidem* and leave only *quod/quantum sciam* alone to mean about the same, but *equidem* certainly adds here a concessive/apologetic flavor. ("as for me").

Searching for *quantum equidem* yields indeed [two results](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=quantum%20equidem). (*quantum equidem intellego/animadverti*).

Comment: But would *equidem* work for "as far as he can tell"? Quod equidem sciam, it implies the first person.

Comment: @TKR, Good point. I've just skimmed the PHI and could not find *equidem* with other body but the first person singular. So I guess it won't work.